# jquery if statement detecting if there are tr with "X" class below

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply  css rules to tr elements depending on what class would be the following tr.

ex.

```
<table>
<tr class="x"/>
<tr class="y"/>
<tr class="x"/>
<tr class="x"/>
</table>
```

So those tr with class x that have a following tr with class y will have different css style than those tr that the next tr is with class x.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
  if ($("tr.x").next('(tr.y)')) {

        $(this).css({'background-color' : 'yellow', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});

      }
  else{

       $(this).css({'background-color' : 'blue', 'font-weight' : 'normal'});

      }
});
</script>
```

It is not working at all and I don't know why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I wanted to apply the css style to the first td of the tr, and I am trying;

```
$(this).first('td').css({ 'color': 'Blue',});
```

But still apply it to the row.

Thanks again to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My updated answer is inspired by [Sarfraz's original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768209/jquery-if-statement-detecting-if-there-are-tr-with-x-class-below/3768250#3768250), but he went a different way in the end, so posting here instead:

```
$('tr.x:has(+ tr.y)').css({ ... });
```

That uses a [sibling combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#sibling-combinators) with a `:has` test. (I'm not sure whether `:has` is a [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/)-specific thing [Sizzle being the selector engine used by jQuery and others] or of there's a proposal out there; it's not specified by CSS3, and so not standard...yet?)

Live example: http://jsbin.com/imeso4/3

**Update** If you want to apply styling to the first *child cell* of that row, you're looking for the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-child-pseudo) selector:

```
$('tr.x:has(+ tr.y) td:first-child').css({ ... });
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/imeso4/8

Or if you want to do something with the rows, and then also do something with the cells, break it up:

```
var rows = $('tr.x:has(+ tr.y)');
rows.css({color: 'blue'});
rows.find('td:first-child').css({color: 'red'});
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/imeso4/7

---

<s>Original (plodding) answer:</s>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('tr.x').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var next = $this.next('tr');
        if (next.length > 0 && next.hasClass('y')) {
            // This tr is class x followed by class y
        }
    });

});
```

Live example: http://jsbin.com/imeso4

Comment: I wanted to apply the css style to the first td of the tr, and I am trying;

$(this).first('td').css({ 'color': 'Blue',});
But still apply it to the row

Comment: @Cesar: You're looking for `td:first-child`, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Thanks for your reply, I think I did not explain myself well, I would need to apply style to the first td of each tr that has pass the condition. Once again Thanks.

Comment: @Cesar: No worries, that was clear. That's what my update does. Check out the live examples.

Comment: @Cesar: No worries. And if you haven't already given Sarfraz an up-vote, I would -- his answers were also on target (much more so than my original was, but I've improved it a lot since then).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$('.x + .y').prev().css({'background-color' : 'yellow', 'font-weight' : 'bolder'});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/imeso4/4)

Comment: This would style the .y elements, not the .x elements.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I took the liberty of updating it for you.

Comment: @Sarfaz: Ah, overlapping edits, you wiped mine out with a different, but also working, example.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Yup i was editing and did not know you had edited already :)

Comment: @Sarfraz: I posted my alternate to the above in my answer. Both are good, kudos again for the `+`.

Comment: I wanted to apply the css style to the first td of the tr, and I am trying;

$(this).first('td').css({ 'color': 'Blue',});
But still apply it to the row

Comment: @Cesar: You need to use this code: `$(this).find('td:first').css({ 'color': 'Blue',});`

Comment: @Sarfraz: Thank you for your answer, I am going to use T.J. solution as I understand it better. But I will look into your as it looks really good too.

Answer (score 1):

You should split this into two: jQuery and CSS. Use CSS to style all the .x elements, and use jQuery to do your special formatting.

```
$(".y").prev(".x").children("td").first().css({'background-color':'yellow', 'font-weight':'bolder'});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/enova4

**Edit:** Actually, you should just add a class to your "special" .x elements, and perform ALL styling in CSS. I also adjusted the code to address the first child td.

```
$(".y").prev(".x").children("td").first().addClass('x-special');

...
<style>
.x-special {
  background-color: yellow;
  font-weight: bolder;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer, at the moment it would only apply to the first td of the first row, I need it to do it for the first td of all rows.

Comment: Good point - use children("td:first-child") instead of children("td").first() should do the trick :)